# pending intent not working in notificationbar

Tags: android

i have this code

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .setTicker("Ticker")
              .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
              .setAutoCancel(true)
              .setContentText("Text")
              .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,myActivity.class), 0));
          NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

          notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

i run this code on htc one mini with android 4.3 and it is working correctly
but when i run this code on nexus 5(android:4.4.2 runtime:art) and when i clicked on the notification myActivity didn't start and only remove my notification(AutoCancle)
any ideas?thanks in advance

Comment: Check my answer. I guess the problem is with "this" keyword.You either need to use your context or "yourActivity.this."

Comment: but why it works on android 4.3 ?

Comment: You are running in "art".Check with "dvm".

Comment: yes the problem is art !

Comment: yes it works on dalvik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
private void addNotification(Context context, String message) {

  int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
  String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
 .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  Notification notification;
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
  new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);


 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
 context);
 notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
.setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
.setContentText(message).build();

 notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);

}
```

You need to pass current Context for creating mBuilder object.

Also, please run your app in "*Dalvik Virtual machine(DVM)*" instead of "*Android Run time(ART)*".

Check this link : https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html

**Note :**  Dalvik must remain the default runtime or you risk breaking your Android implementations and third-party applications.

Hope this helps.